# cannot resolve symbol GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICE_UPDATE_CODE

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am getting this problem while try to using google play services even I include playservices in build.gragle file and this code in manifest file.

```
<meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

here is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xyz.in.googleplayservice"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(':libs:ViewPagerIndicator')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.2.0'
compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

my activity where I include this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashactivity);
    alert = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.alert);
    mGoogleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    try {
        int status = mGoogleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if(mGoogleApiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(status)) {
                mGoogleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, status,0
                        , new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Are you want to update ?")
                                        .setTitle("Google play service Out of date.Google play services need to be Updated, tou are unable to use this app without updating your google services.")
                                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                dialog.cancel();
                                                finish();
                                            }
                                        })
                                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                dialog.cancel();
                                                Intent termcondlink = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en"));
                                                startActivity(termcondlink);
                                            }
                                        }).show();
                            }
                        }).show();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("error",e.toString());
    }
    mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SharedPrefUtil.PREFERENCES,MODE_PRIVATE);
    final Context context = this ;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("run","after 2 sec");
            if ( UtilFunctions.isNetworkAvailable(context)){
                isNetworkActive();
            }
            else {
                if (!UtilFunctions.isNetworkAvailable(context)){
                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.disconnected_network, null);
                    builder.setView(view);
                    Button Tryagain = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.tryagain);
                    builder.setCancelable(false);
                    final Dialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                    Tryagain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                            if (!UtilFunctions.isNetworkAvailable(context)){
                                dialog.show();
                            } else {
                                isNetworkActive();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}
```

Comment: can you post your build.gradle?

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: Edited my question, check it.

Comment: Can you include the code where you're having this error. I am not sure that constant comes from the library.

Comment: Did you make sure to update the build.gradle file? did you rebuild/clean the project? Make sure you're not working offline and you have a good Internet connection (the gradle needs to be able to access the Internet)

Comment: Yes I have clean and rebuild the projects many time